# Facing trouble solving higher order heat equation.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-transform, heat-equation, hypergeometric-function, linear-pde

I am facing trouble solving this higher order heat equation
$$\partial_t u +\partial_x^4 u = 0,   \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space -\infty<x<\infty, t>0$$ 
$$u(x, t) =0, \space  u_x(x, t) =0, \space  u_{xx}(x, t) =0,\space u_{xxx}(x, t) =0,  \space  as  \space x→±∞, t>0,$$

$$ u(x, 0) = \Theta $$
where $\Theta$ is a Heaviside function. The problem I am facing is I am getting an integration of this hypergeometric function ([hypergeometric function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJ4di.png)) 
which I am not able to perform. If anyone can help me solve this problem I would be thankful.

I am sorry that I am not able to post image as my reputation is below 10!

Thank you!

Comment: You might want to try a Laplace transform, it might be able to deal with the Heaviside function a little easier, also the resulting differential equation in $U(x,s)$ is of fourth order and your initial conditions make it very easy to simplify it down.